# Using thumbs_up gem while iterating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

I'm using the thumbs_up gem in my application and I'm trying to figure out the best way to save votes in my controller while iterating.

Here is my model:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :inventory_items
    has_many    :items, through: :inventory_items
    has_many    :shopping_lists, through: :inventory_items

    acts_as_voteable
end
```

my current controller:

```
def vote_for_vendor
    # not sure what to put in here
end

def vote_against_vendor
    # not sure what to put in here
end
```

my current view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Stores') %>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">

<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Favorite?</th>
</tr>

    <% @vendors.each do |v| %>
<tr>

    <td><%= v.name %></td>
    <td><%= v.address %></td>
    <td>
        <% if current_user.voted_for(v) %>
            <%= link_to 'unlike', vote_against_vendor_vendors_path(vendor_id: v.id), :remote => true %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to 'like', vote_for_vendor_vendors_path(vendor_id: v.id), :remote => true %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Most of the examples I've seen have used `params([])` to pass the relevant information to the controller. I don't really have params because this is just my index page that shows all vendors. How can I save votes using this gem while iterating? Thanks in advance!

**Updated Controller w/ help from MrYoshi**

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @vendors = Vendor.all
    end

    def vote_for_vendor
        vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
        current_user.vote_for(vendor)

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end

    def vote_against_vendor
        vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
        current_user.vote_against(vendor)

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

my routes:

```
resources :vendors do
    collection { post :vote_for_vendor }
    collection { post :vote_agaist_vendor }
  end
```

**Current Server Error**

Started GET "/vendors/vote_for_vendor?vendor_id=4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-06 10:07:29 -0700

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for VendorsController):

...........

Rendered /Users/#Myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/unknown_action.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you the start of what you want, and you will be able to do the rest by yourself I think:

View:

```
<% if current_user.voted_for(v) %>
  <%= link_to 'unlike', vote_against_vendor_vendors_path(vendor_id: v.id), :remote => true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'like', vote_for_vendor_vendors_path(vendor_id: v.id), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def vote_for_vendor
  vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
  current_user.vote_for(vendor)

  render :nothing => true
end
```

And the vote_against is pretty simple to guess now that you have this one above ;)

Comment: Ah cool I see how that works. Nice. I'm getting the page rendered now, but my votes aren't submitting. I've updated my controller to reflect the changes. I had to add collections for these routes to get them working. I added those as well, because I'm not sure they're set up correctly. Also, I added the format block for js and ajax. Not sure why my votes aren't submitting, thoughts?

Comment: What is the error raised @settheline? 404 Not found? No route matches [url]? Nothing at all?

Comment: Is the request sent? Does your server receive the request? What happens when it does receive the request?

Comment: Checked it out and the request is getting sent to the server. I've updated the question with server error.

Comment: You need to add `render :nothing => true` at the end of your actions in order to stop the server from redirecting/rendering any other action.

Comment: I reconfigured my `link_to` to a `button_to` and reconfigured my controller methods as well. I'm not getting votes submitted correctly. I'm not worrying about callback or anything fancy until I get the `unlike` function working. Started a new question to tackle that. If you have a moment, give it a peek please! Your answer here helped me figure out the iteration aspect of it, so thank you!      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666945/thumbs-up-gem-rails-how-to-take-back-a-vote

Answer (score 0):

For your 'current server error' (`AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for VendorsController):`), you need to add a **member route** to your `config/routes.rb` file, like this:

```
resources :vendors do
  member do
    post 'vote_for_vendor'
    post 'vote_against_vendor'
  end
end
```

You are currently using collection routes which are for resources that don't need a particular ID to work.  I highly recommend reading the Rails Guide on routes:

[Rails Guide Documentation on Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time#adding-more-restful-actions)